# Nagios: HTTP checks with XMPP, notifications missing the URL

Tags: nagios

We're using a Nagios installation to watch over our infrastructure and alot of websites. The way the websites are monitored is by using `check_http` with the URL passed as a parameter. We use this, because multiple websites are hosted on the same systems, and the URLs can reasonably change because the URL key of products can change.

So the HTTP checks basically look like this:

```
define service {
        host_name                               ourhostname
        service_description                     Typo 3
        check_command                           check_http!www.ourdomain.com!/
        max_check_attempts                      3
        check_interval                          1
        retry_interval                          1
        check_period                            24x7
        notification_interval                   30
        notification_period                     24x7
        contact_groups                          developers
}
```

And there's the problem. When a notification worthy problem arises, sendxmpp is called like this:

```
define command {
        command_name    notify-service-by-xmpp
        command_line    echo "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $ARG1$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /usr/bin/sendxmpp -j <server-ip> -u nagios -p <password> $CONTACTPAGER$
}
```

Where we tried to use `$ARG1$`, we would need the checked URL. It seems that the notification has access to the standard variables for the problematic object (for example `$HOSTADDRESS$`), but we need the URL.

The problem could also be that I am checking URLs wrong. Usually, you only have a `HOSTADDRESS` entry, but it seemed wrong to document the URLs in the host definition, then add multiple commands to check `$HOSTADDRESS1$` through `$HOSTADDRESS15$`.

Does anybody either have a solution on how to access the command line argument passed to the test, or a better idea on how to check a whole lot of URLs for the same host under different vhosts without opening either multiple different commands or different hosts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a better solution but this seems to be a use case for custom variables (reference: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/customobjectvars.html)

Just add something like this to your service definition:

```
_domain             www.ourdomain.com
```

Then you can use it at the notification command as **$_DOMAIN$**

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that I either need multiple check commands using parameters _HOSTADDRESS1 to _HOSTADDRESSX, or pass _HOSTADDRESSX to the check command as a parameter, leaving me at the same problem I was before?

Comment: You currently have multiple service definitions right?
At that definition add the above line - after contact groups for instance.

No need to add more check commands, and you can either use this variable or keep things with ARG1 as they are at the check command.

You can however reference to the variable at your notification command.

Comment: Ah, use the custom var at the service definition, not at the host definition. Will try that, thank you. Might take a bit. Will definitely give feedback.

Comment: And you can use that same custom var in the check command, too, so you don't have to write ourdomain.com twice in the service def

Comment: Maybe you have an idea, before I post a new question: As I am now informing about the service having problems, I have the host's address in $HOSTADDRESS$ and the URI part in $_SERVICEDOMAIN$. Copying those together doesn't work: $HOSTADDRESS$$_SERVICEDOMAIN$ gives the host address with a $ at the end, which is probably by $$ being a literal $. I worked around it by adding a space in between, but this is not picked up as a link by the XMPP client at the end. Any idea how to work around this?

Comment: I don't know how to do that in nagios, quick search in documentation doesn't turn up anything. However if you're doing something like echo "$HOSTADDRESS$$_SERVICEDOMAIN$" you can probably split it into echo "$HOSTADDRESS$""$_SERVICEDOMAIN" and it should work.